# Proving that a set is countable (or not)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the set $$\left \{ (u,v)\in\mathbb{Q}^2:u-v\in \mathbb{Z}  \right \}$$ is indeed countable and that
$$\left \{ (u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2:u-v\in \mathbb{Q}  \right \}$$
is not

---

By instinct I would say the first set is countable as $u-v\in \mathbb{Z} $ and that the rationals are countable (and thus the cart. prod.) but how does one rigorously show that a set is either countable or uncountable?

I know that a set $S$ is countable if its cardinality is less than or equal to $\aleph_0$.
The second one instinctly is also not countable to me as the elements are from $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: The first set is a subset of a countable set. For the second one you can easily show that it contains an uncountable subset (given that $ \mathbb{R} $ is uncountable, it is not that difficult).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one remember that both $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Q^2$ are countable, and with $q\to(q,q)$ there is an injection from $\mathbb Q$ into the set. Thus the set is countable as well.

For the second one: We again have that $x\to(x,x)$ injects $\mathbb R$ into your set. So the set cannot be countable (as it contains an injective image of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So we don't actually use the fact $u-v$? We just say that a injection exists? I am not completly sure on the argument.

Comment: oh - when you say "into the set" do you mean the one in question?

Comment: Yes, I mean the set in question. The injection is defined by $q\to(q,q)$ or $x\to(x,x)$. As $q-q=0=x-x$ and $0\in\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb Q$ this maps $q$ or $x$ into the set and is trivially injective.

Comment: But it is not the same element? where are we getting $q-q$ and $x-x$ from when it is $u-v$?

Comment: Yes it is. The set consists of all pairs $(u,v)$ to that $u-v$ is in $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$. In particular if we choose $u=v$ then this holds true. Note that we only need to get an injection, not a surjection, so we are perfectly fine with only getting that subset.

Comment: I see so q and x are elements of the rationals and the reals respectively?

Comment: Yes, so that we map the whole of $\mathbb Q$ injectively into the set.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an ambiguity about countable, which some use to mean countably infinite and others to include finite sets as well. I generally include finite sets because it allows me to say that a subset of a countable set is countable. And that is useful to prove a set countable - because we might be able to see that it is a subset of a known countable set.

For proving a set uncountable, the same idea allows us to show that some subset of the original is uncountable.

These observations, like the fact that the Cartesian product of countable sets is countable, become part of a toolkit which enables us to prove that sets are countable or uncountable without going back to absolute basics every time, and by reference to a known collection of countable and uncountable sets.

To use this principle in your toolkit, you first have to prove it as rigorously as required in your context.

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the comment. I see what you are saying. I think it is sufficient for me to say that the cartesian product of countable sets is countable and the fact that I know $\mathbb{R}$ is not. I, however, am not using the $u-v\in X$ fact.